# Append cell to a different cell

Tags: excel, vba

I Have a Column C that has names in all its cells and another Column E that has the same company name in all its cells I need to append the names in Column C to the company name in column E

Thanks

Ex:

```
ColC  ColE
Bob   SampleCo
Sally SamplCo
```

I get

```
ColC  ColE
Bob  SampleCo Bob
Sally SamplCo Sally
```

I am trying but failing with

```
Sub CompanyName()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim rRange As range


 Set rRange = range("E2")
 rRange.Select

Set Ws = Sheets("WP_SubjectList_Ready")

LastRow = Ws.range("F" & Ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Ws.range("E2:E" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=rRange &RC[-1]"

range("E2:E" & LastRow).Copy
range("E2:E" & LastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Comment: All you want to do is create a macro that put in collum E the value in collumn E, " " and the value in column C of the same row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code

```
Sub CompanyName()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Ws As Worksheet

    Set Ws = Sheets("WP_SubjectList_Ready")
    LastRow = Ws.Range("E" & Ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Ws.Range("F2:F" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "= RC[-1] & "" "" & RC[-3]"

End Sub
```

[image]

If you want the output in `Column E` its not possible using `FormulaR1C1`.
Any formula which work for excel interface will work for `FormulaR1C1`.
With that i mean (considering the image) in cell `F2` you can manullay enter a formula `= E2 & " " & C2` which will give you desired output. But if you enter in cell `E2`the formula as `=E2 & " " & C2` the cell `E2` will loose its value and this may even lead to circular reference issue.

It can be achieved using below code.

```
Sub CompanyName()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

    Set Ws = Sheets("WP_SubjectList_Ready")
    LastRow = Ws.Range("E" & Ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Ws.Range("E2:E" & LastRow)

    For Each cell In rng
        cell = cell & " " & cell.Offset(0, -2)
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Santosh it worked perfectly. I was concerned I was creating a bad function by pasting back into the E column.  I will Google `cell.Offset()` and read up on it, it looks like a valuable technique.  `Thank You`

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code that should help you with what you want...I don't typically use ranges for loops because  it's easier to use .Cells(row, col) for me, but anyways:

**EDIT:** Added Sub Opening/Closing Syntax and edited to use WS instead of ActiveSheet so it's closer to what you want

```
Sub CompanyName()
Dim WS as Worksheet
Dim vRow
Dim vRowCount As Integer

Set WS = Sheets("WP_SubjectList_Ready")

'Gets Row # of Last Row for Column E
vRowCount = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

'Assuming Both Columns have the same row count and you have a header row
For vRow = 2 To vRowCount
    WS.Cells(vRow, 5).Value = WS.Cells(vRow, 5).Value & " " & WS.Cells(vRow, 3).Value
Next vRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Kurt it worked great, thank you.  I will study how you did this it will help me understand better.